# Why does multiplying uint8_t with an integer result in a 0?

Tags: c, for-loop

I tried to code a program, but i'm having problems with 1 small segment.

```
for(uint8_t i = 1; i < MAX_BIT_VALUE; i*=2){
            printf("Current value of i: %u\n", i);
}
```

When I run this segment, I get this output:

> Current value of i: 0
>
> Current value of i: 0
>
> Current value of i: 0
>
> Current value of i: 0

in an infinite loop. I don't understand why. `uint8_t` is an unsigned integer of 8-bits. I merely multiplied `i` which has value 1 by 2. How could it possibly become 0?

If i changed the data type of `i` to `int` however, it works just fine:

> Current value of i: 1
>
> Current value of i: 2
>
> Current value of i: 4
>
> Current value of i: 8
>
> Current value of i: 16

...

I tried to find a possible answer online, but I don't know how to phrase the problem to get an answer. Could you guys help me please?

Comment: Please show the very first lines of output, I suspect that we will see 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,0,0,0,0,0,...

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: What is MAX_BIT_VALUE defined as?

Comment: @Shrewmouse #define MAX_BIT_VALUE 65536

Comment: See my answer, uint8_t is not big enough to store 255.  when 128*=2, i get's truncated to 0 and never leaves the for loop because 0 < MAX_BIT_VALUE is always true and 0*=2 will always be 0.

Comment: sorry I meant that you don't have enough bits to represent 256

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from what the other answer recommend on the printing, you have the following problem:

- multipy i==128 by 2
- result 256
- storing it 256 (0x100) in an unsigned 8bit results in 0,
  because 8 bit are to narrow
- multiply 0 by 2
- result 0
- 0 < 255 -> endless loop

Comment: Integer overflow! Why didn't I think of that! You're a genius Yunnosch. Thank you! :D

Comment: I changed uint8_t to uint32_t, and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Your code causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The flag value `#` is not supposed to be used with `u` conversion specifier.

Quoting `C11`,chapter §7.21.6.1

> `#` The result is converted to an ‘‘alternative form’’. For `o` conversion, it increases
>   the precision, if and only if necessary, to force the first digit of the result to be a
>   zero (if the value and precision are both 0, a single 0 is printed). For `x` (or `X`)
>   conversion, a nonzero result has `0x` (or `0X`) prefixed to it. For `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`,
>   and `G` conversions, the result of converting a floating-point number always
>   contains a decimal-point character, even if no digits follow it. (Normally, a
>   decimal-point character appears in the result of these conversions only if a digit
>   follows it.) For `g` and `G` conversions, trailing zeros are not removed from the
>   result. **For other conversions, the behavior is undefined.**

For fixed width integers use the format specifier MACROS as defined in `inttypes.h`, like `PRIu8` for a 8-bit unsigned integer type.

---

After you fix this the next problem is, overflow of the 8-bit variable. As [described in the other answer by **Yunnosch**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45963180/2173917) Once `i` becomes `128`, you multiple it by 2, and store the result back in the 8-bit variable, the result is  `0`. Then,

- 0  multiplied by anything remains 0
- which constitutes a forever TRUE condition in the `for` loop, `i < MAX_BIT_VALUE` part.

and you get the infinite loop.

Comment: I removed the #, and the results are still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Change the printf format string from:

> printf("Current value of i: %#u\n", i);

to

> printf("Current value of i: %"PRIu8"\n", i);

and it should be fine. The PRIu8 macro is defined in inttypes.h